# Sudden "no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" error

Tags: nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

I have a config like this **which has worked for years**:

```
  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
      return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
  }


  # !!!!
  # line 10
  server {
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      server_name www.domain.com;
      return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

      server_name domain.com;


      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
      ssl_session_timeout 180m;
      ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
      ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000';

      # [.................]
  }
```

Now it's begun to fail due to the error:

```
no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com:10
```

What has changed in nginx? How to fix it?

Comment: Unless you disclose the name of the OS/distribution you're using and the exact version number of the `nginx` package you have now, any answers are going to be based on guesswork. The package management system usually has a log of some kind: check it to see if `nginx` package was recently updated, and from/to which version. Then check your distribution's (or its "parent" distribution's) webpage for a package catalog, which might include a change log. There you can find exactly what was changed.

Answer (score 2):

Your `server` block is missing `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` statements.

You can move these statements outside of any `server` block so that the same certificate is used by all `server` blocks (assuming that you just have the one certificate).

Nginx can be bit relaxed about 'no "ssl_certificate" is defined' errors. I suspect that if the `server` blocks were reversed, the error might mysteriously disappear. But for correctness, you should define a certificate for each `server` block that needs one, or in `http` block scope for all servers.

Comment: once again: I have a config like this which HAS WORKED FOR YEARS

Comment: Your `server` block without a `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` statements starting from line 10 **should never have worked**: you cannot have a HTTPS server without a certificate. It looks like there was a bug that allowed the certificate configuration to "leak" from one `server` block to another - and now that bug has apparently been fixed.

Comment: @telcoM IT HAS ALWAYS WORKED, ON DIFFERENT MACHINES, FOR YEARS

Comment: That does not change the fact that your configuration probably relied on a nginx bug to work. Now the bug has been fixed and such a relaxed configuration style no longer works. Richard Smith already told you what needs to be done. If you don’t like it, then you must downgrade nginx to a version that still has that configuration bug. That might be a risky thing to do.